# Can't access classes written in separate file but in same namespace and in same folder (ASP.NET Web Application)

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-organization

I have following file structure as below image

[image]

My Project name is `myIGNOU` and class classes in all the these file inside `App_Code` folder are written in `myIGNOU` `namespace` .

But something is really irritating me that I can access class from `AppSettings.cs` file in `Code2.cs` file but can't access the same class from `AppSettings.cs` in `Code1.cs`. I tried just swapping the file names of `Code1.cs` and `Code2.cs` but no luck, still very same behavior. I have also tried adding another class (in separate file) in same folder but I still can't access any class of `AppSettings.cs` file in this newly created class.

Why there is no button to expand any other file but just `Code1.cs` when I have some classes (all public) in each file..?

What am I missing ..? I have also tried renaming `App_Code` folder but again no luck.
While all classes of file `Code1.cs` can be accessed in rest of the classes.

**I think any of these three files are not being compiled coz if I type anything wrong like `lasdk;adj.j` I won't get any compile time error. But I am getting `Compilation Error` at runtime. Same is not true for other files not in this folder like `Default.aspx.cs`. For this I will get error at compiling.**

[You can see all code here](http://bdn2.com/App_Code.zip)

Here is code

### AppSettings.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace myIGNOU
{
    public static class AppSettings
    {
        //public static string ConnectionString { get { return "Data Source = .; Initial Catalog = SMR; Integrated Security = True;"; } }
        //public static string ConnectionString2 { get { return "Data Source = .; Initial Catalog = shashwat; Integrated Security = True;"; } }
        public static string ConnectionString { get { return "Data Source=IDCSQL2.znetlive.com,1234;Initial Catalog=smrbobdn;User Id=shashwat;Password=xxxx;"; } }
        public static string ConnectionString2 { get { return "Data Source=IDCSQL2.znetlive.com,1234;Initial Catalog=shashwat;User Id=shashwat;Password=xxxx;"; } }
        public static string ConStr1 { get { return "Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=myIGNOU; Integrated Security=true;"; } }

        public static DateTime Now { get { return DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(0); } }
    }
}
```

### Code1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace myIGNOU
{
    public class Student
    {
        public Student(string enrollmentNumber)
        {
            EN = enrollmentNumber;
        }
        public bool LoadFromDB()
        {
            bool ret = false;
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM StudentInfo WHERE EN = @en", new SqlConnection());

            return ret;
        }
        public string EN { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public string FatherName { get; private set; }
        public string Program { get; private set; }
        public string Address { get; private set; }
        public string Mobile { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public uint RC { get; private set; }
        public uint SC { get; private set; }
        public uint AdmissionYear { get; private set; }
        public uint AdmissionValid { get; private set; }
        public uint UpdatedOn { get; private set; }
    }

    public class HttpRequest
    {

        string GetPageAsString(string path, string method, string dataToPost)
        {
           return "...";
        }
    }



    public class Program
    {
    }
    public class Semester
    {
    }
    public class Course
    {
    }
}
```

### Code2.cs

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace myIGNOU
{
    public class CustomHttpRequest
    {

    }
    public class Emails
    {
        public static MailAddressCollection GetAllEmails()
        {
            MailAddressCollection cc = new MailAddressCollection();
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT Email from myignou", new SqlConnection(AppSettings.ConnectionString));
            com.Connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                cc.Add(dr[0].ToString());
            }
            com.Connection.Close();
            return cc;
        }
    }
    public class RegexUtilities
    {
        public static bool IsValidEmail(string strIn)
        {
            // Return true if strIn is in valid e-mail format.
            return Regex.IsMatch(strIn,
                   @"^(?("")(""[^""]+?""@)|(([0-9a-zA-Z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-zA-Z])@))" +
                   @"(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}))$");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: dont use zip file show code and maybe someother person will benefit from your code

Comment: Is SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT Email from myignou", new SqlConnection(AppSettings.ConnectionString)); the line that causes a compile time error in Code2.cs?

Comment: @ben no sorry.. Actually it is Code1.cs where I can't access class of `Appsettings.cs`. I have just edited your code

Comment: ok @skhurams. Just added code. I thought would make my question vague

Comment: I'm assuming LoadFromDB() function is the one where you'd like to access the Appsettings class from? Try making this a static method. @harsh

Comment: no @Ben. Making this function static didn't help anyhow

Comment: Oh in that case where exactly in Code1.cs are you trying to access AppSettings class? @harsh

Comment: same as u assumed @Ben. inside `new SqlConnection(<here>)` in `LoadFromDB()` function

Comment: What error message(s) are you getting? Have you tried `Build/clean` and recompiling everything?

Comment: actually @radarbob! I think any of these three files are not being compiled coz if I type anything wrong like `lasdk;adj.j` I won't get any compile time error. But I am getting `Compilation Error` at runtime. Same is not true for other files not in this folder like `Default.aspx.cs`. For this I will get error at compiling.